# Exception when upgrading Power BI Embedded nuget packages from beta to 1.0

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

As Power BI Embedded release to official version 1.0, I tried to upgrade PowerBI nuget packages in my application from version beta to 1.0, everything works perfectly on localhost.

But when I deploy to the web server (IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2), I got exception:

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ada706e8\d6adc8aa\App_Web_index.cshtml.1c5a15dd.b_ofojaq.0.cs(77): error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I am not sure how to fix it, my application on .NET 4.6.1. I had to go back beta version for production until finding the way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fixed by adding the line:

```
<add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

into web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
  ....
</compilation>
```